# Ein Glück gibt es... Grammar identification

Tags: grammar-identification

Die gängige Formulierung lautet

> **Zum Glück** habe ich mein Auto gestern in die Garage gefahren. Heute hat es heftig gehagelt.

Ich kenne aber auch

> **Ein Glück** habe ich ...

Heute bin ich stutzig geworden, da das ziemlich ungrammatikalisch aussieht. Wie ist diese Konstruktion zu erklären?

Falls die Region relevant ist, könnte es SH, NDS oder HE sein.

Comment: Wie hieße der zweite Satz vollständig? "Ein Glück habe ich mein Auto gestern in die Garage gefahren." würde ich nicht für richtig halten. Jedoch: "Ein Glück habe ich heute wieder gehabt, denn es hat heftig gehagelt und ich hatte mein Auto in die Garage gefahren." Hier dient das "Ein Glück" zur Betonung. So wie in "Einen Hunger habe ich heute". Oder: "Ein Idiot ist er schon."

Comment: Was mir zumindest einfällt ist, dass man sagen kann "Was ein Glück, dass ..." Ob das zu der Verkürzung geführt hat, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: @infinitezero wenn schon, dann bitte "was **für** ein Glück", dass... ".

Comment: Ich bitte um Verzeihung

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ein Glück haben wir noch Tiefkühlpizza.

Das Unbehagen stammt daher, daß *ein Glück* hier adverbial, mit der Bedeutung *zum Glück* gebraucht wird, ohne daß es irgendeine Markierung dafür gäbe. Vielleicht findet man es auch unangenehm, daß man *ein Glück* zunächst als Objekt von *haben* auffaßt, dies aber korrigieren muß, wenn man bei *Tiefkühlpizza* ankommt.

Eine mögliche Herleitung ist die folgende. Aus einem Satzgefüge werden zwei unabhängige Hauptsätze (1. → 2.), dann kommt es zur Reanalyse des ersten Hauptsatzes bzw. eines Teils davon als adverbiale Bestimmung innerhalb des zweiten Satzes (2. → 3.).

> 1. [Es ist] ein Glück, dass wir noch Tiefkühlpizza haben.
>
> 2. [Es ist] ein Glück! Wir haben noch Tiefkühlpizza.
>
> 3. Ein Glück haben wir noch Tiefkühlpizza.

Ähnlich vielleicht bei *Gott sei Dank*:

> 1. Gott sei Dank, dass wir noch Tiefkühlpizza haben.
>
> 2. Gott sei Dank! Wir haben noch Tiefkühlpizza.
>
> 3. Gott sei Dank haben wir noch Tiefkühlpizza.

Answer (score -2):

Folgendes ist richtig:

> **Zum Glück** habe ich mein Auto gestern in die Garage gefahren. Heute hat es heftig gehagelt.

Jedoch kenne ich das zweite Beispiel nur so:

> **Ein Glück**, `ich habe` mein Auto gestern in die Garage gefahren. Heute hat es heftig gehagelt.

Comment: Hi :) Vielleicht fallen dir noch ein oder zwei Sätze ein, die das ganze begründen oder/und ausführen..

Comment: Es wird im Opening Post nicht gefragt, was richtig ist, sondern wie das Phänomen grammatisch beschrieben und klassifiziert ("erklärt") werden kann. Daher gebe ich hier -1